# How to use looping to Autofit columns for a different workbooks using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I've a master sheet contains some data for many departments employees, i tried to use python for extracting every department data in another single sheet with a specific format.
i've tried after a long searching and working on the below code to do what i want except two things.

1- i need to autofit the columns in every extracted single sheet as the data format is not good to send it to the concerned departments.(The data view like to be the below PS)

**The Original data that i found:-**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hvIR.png)

**The Data that i need to view:-**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/og34d.png)

**The Code That i've used it:-**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Border, Side, Alignment, Protection, Font,colors,Fill,GradientFill
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import ColorScaleRule, CellIsRule, FormulaRule, Rule
from openpyxl.styles.differential import DifferentialStyle
from openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions import ColumnDimension
import datetime

df=pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Mahmoud.Bader\Desktop\FP Attendance V1.6 Apr 22.xlsx","Attendance").fillna("")
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.date


dep = list(df["Department"].unique())

for i in dep:
    FP_Attendance = df[df["Department"].str.contains(i)]
    FP_Attendance=FP_Attendance.style.set_properties(**{'color':'black','text-align': 'center','font-family': 'Arial Narrow','border-color':'Black','border-width':'thin','border-style':'solid','vertical-align': 'middle'})
    with pd.ExcelWriter(f"C:\\Users\\Mahmoud.Bader\\Desktop\\Python\\Workforce Reports\\FP Test\\{i}.xlsx",engine='openpyxl') as writer:
        FP_Attendance.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=str(i), index=False,freeze_panes=(1,0))
           
    wb = load_workbook(f"C:\\Users\\Mahmoud.Bader\\Desktop\\Python\\Workforce Reports\\FP Test\\{i}.xlsx")
    ws = wb[str(i)]
   
    
    col_range = ws.max_column
    for col in range(1, col_range + 1):
        cell_header = ws.cell(1, col)
        cell_header.font = Font(color='00FFFFFF',name='Arial Narrow',size=11,bold=True)
        cell_header.fill = PatternFill(start_color='00C00000', end_color='00C00000', fill_type="solid")
        cell_header.alignment =  Alignment(horizontal="center", vertical="center")
        thin = Side(border_style="thin", color="000000")
        cell_header.border =  Border(top=thin, left=thin, right=thin, bottom=thin)
        
        
        ws.conditional_formatting.add('I2:I10000',CellIsRule(operator='greaterThan', formula=[0], stopIfTrue=False, font=Font(color="00FF0000",bold=True)))
        ws.conditional_formatting.add('F2:L10000', FormulaRule(formula=['NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("OFF Day",F2)))'], stopIfTrue=True, font=Font(color="00000000",bold=True),fill=PatternFill(start_color='00BFBFBF', end_color='00BFBFBF', fill_type='solid'))) 
        ws.conditional_formatting.add('F2:L10000', FormulaRule(formula=['NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("No Show",F2)))'], stopIfTrue=True, font=Font(color="009C0006",bold=True),fill=PatternFill(start_color='00FFC7CE', end_color='00FFC7CE', fill_type='solid')))
        ws.conditional_formatting.add('F2:L10000', FormulaRule(formula=['NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("Annual",F2)))'], stopIfTrue=True, font=Font(color="00006100",bold=True),fill=PatternFill(start_color='00C6EFCE', end_color='00C6EFCE', fill_type='solid')))
        ws.auto_filter.ref = "A1:O15"
        ws.sheet_properties.tabColor = "00C00000"
        ws.sheet_view.showGridLines = False

        wb.save(f"C:\\Users\\Mahmoud.Bader\\Desktop\\Python\\Workforce Reports\\FP Test\\{i}.xlsx")
```

**The Master sheet link:-**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R-DdbWwikQVo2JsKO5ZwVdhlFTmtipUN/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=113199804085037794899&rtpof=true&sd=true

**The Final sheet that i expect to found:-**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9lWF.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i provided you with the full code that i've used and described my full issue, also i've provided you with the master sheet link that i use, So what should i do more than this?

Comment: how do you want to fill the missing data? Do you want to interpolate, fill with the mean, median, mode... what exactly do u want to replace the empty fields with? Also the column Lateness Duration is completely empty, how do you want to fill it?

Comment: i'm talking about specific columns (Start Shift, End Shift, Login Time, Logout Time) only

Comment: i need to change the format of those columns to be like the photos that i've provided.

Comment: i've tried to solve the issue by this code but i can't find the way to apply it in my dataFrame   `(for i in df['Start Shift']:
    try:
        if i.isascii() == True:
            print(i)
    except:
        print(i.strftime('%H:%M %p'))`